# Duplicate Class Error in kotlin gradle implementation

Tags: kotlin, gradle, maven-bom

I get duplicate class errors as gradle implementation app's build.gradle file. But I don't know which implementation is actually a duplicate. How can i resolve this? Is there a better way like using bom for the dependencies?

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'

}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.bettehomes'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.bettehomes"
        minSdk 25
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables {
            useSupportLibrary true
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
    buildFeatures {
        compose true
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion compose_version

            }
    packagingOptions {
        resources {
            excludes += '/META-INF/{AL2.0,LGPL2.1}'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {

        // Import the Compose BOM
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.5.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.7.0-alpha04'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.3"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.3.3"
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha04'
    // Android Studio Preview Support

    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:1.3.3"
    //testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:1.4.0-alpha05"
    debugImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest:1.3.3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue today and used `gradle dependencies` to figure out the [dependency tree](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/viewing_debugging_dependencies.html)

I figured out that a lib used a latest version of appcompat which used kotlin 1.8.0, a version that has [this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-55297/kotlin-stdlib-should-declare-constraints-on-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-and-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7).

In my case the fix was to add the `kotlinVersion` manually:

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "32.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 32
        androidXBrowser = "1.4.0"
        
        kotlinVersion = "1.8.0"
    }
...
}
```

For more information check this issue: https://github.com/proyecto26/react-native-inappbrowser/issues/398

Comment: I already have kotlin_version in project's build.gradle. Does any of the depedencies seem redundant?

Comment: I only see kotlinOptions in your code with jvmTarget 1.8. Some libs check on `kotlinVersion` so I added it as such. 
Does it have any error logs?
I edited my comment with the issue in Kotlin.

Comment: @KaleabWoldemariam Note I believe this answer is showing the top-level `build.gradle` file, whereas your question is showing the `build.gradle` file under the `app` directory (I think that's the default name of the directory).

Comment: @Slaw Yes, It is showing app's `build.gradle` file. But I already have kotlin_version (1.7.20) on project's build.gradle.

Comment: Try to upgrade to 1.8.0. This is what helped in our case.